# Relation many to many but not mapped

Tags: php, entity, symfony4

I am setting up a form with many to many entity and a specific query builder to display this in multiple select.

Entity Car.php:

```php
private $id;
private $label;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="cars")
 */
private $user;
```

Entity User :

```php
private $id;
private $name;
private $roles = [];
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Car", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $cars;
```

Form\CarType.php :

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
         ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'multiple'     => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.roles like :role')
                        ->setParameter('role', '%"'.'ROLE_EXPERT'.'"%');
                },
                'choice_label' => function ($user) {
                    return $user->getUsernameFormated();
                },
                'required' => true,

            ])
        ->add('role2', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.roles like :role')
                        ->setParameter('role', '%"'.'ROLE_2'.'"%');
                },
                'mapped' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'choice_label' => function ($user) {
                    return $user->getUsernameFormated();
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une option',
                'label' => 'role2'
    ])
```

CarController.php

```php
 $role2= $form->get('role2')->getData();
 if($role2) $car->addUser($role2);
```

The first field (role1) behaves as expected with the selection of values already in database (because mutliple = true?).

On the other hand, for role2, the value already in base is not selected by default.

When I display the form, the value selected is the placeholder (because multiple = false?)
I want to keep multiple = false for role2.

The goal add user1 with role1 (first field) and user2 with role2 in Entity User.

How I can do this ?

EDIT :
as suggested by  Arleigh Hix, I try with CollectionType.
But to be able to filter the users by roles (to have 2 user fields in the form) I try without success with formEvent

Form\CarType.php :

```php
 ->add('user', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => UsersByRoleType::class,

  ])
```

Form\UsersByRoleType.php

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)  {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $formOptions = [
                'class' => User::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (UserRepository $userRepository)  {

                        return $userRepository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->where('u.roles like :role')
                            ->setParameter('role', '%"'.'ROLE_EXPERT'.'"%');
                    },
                'choice_label' => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'label.role'
            ];

            $form->add('cars', EntityType::class, $formOptions);
```

Comment: Are you trying to add both the `user` and `role2`  selected entities to the `car->user` collection? if so, I think you want to use a CollectionType

Comment: Yes that's exactly the goal.
Both are users with different roles (filtered in the query).